# How can one store a uint64_t in an array?

Tags: arrays, c, data-conversion, unsigned-long-long-int, bit-representation

I am trying to store a `uint64_t` representation of a crc64 checksum as an array.

The checksum will always be like `uint64_t res = 0x72e3daa0aa188782`, so the I want that to be stored as an array, `char digest[8]`, where `digest[0]` is 72, `digest[1]` is e3... `digest[7]` is 82.

I attempted looping/dividing to break up the number, but that would be more appropriate if it was a smaller integer, and if the starting point was Base-10, as the starting point is Base-16, the output should but what is described above.

---

**Update:**  I removed the nonsensical code and wish I can accept all three answers, as they all did what I asked.  The bit shifting is what I was hoping to get as an answer so it is why it is accepted.

Comment: This question is very confusing.  It looks like you're trying to convert a 64-bit value to decimal, but you're using floating-point operations to do it.  You're likely to have error.  Furthermore, you have an array of 19 digits but you're iterating over 20 of them.  If I remove the last digit from your output (which is undefined behavior) and convert to hex I get `72E3DAA0AA188CEC` which is close but clearly incorrect in the last digits.  This is expected, due to precision being lost via calculations using `double`.

Comment: Recommendation 1: do not hard-code your loop length.  If your length is `digit`, then you should do `for (i = 0; i < digit; ++i)`

Comment: Recommendation 2: use only integer arithmetic to convert your value to decimal, or simply use `sprintf` or similar to convert it to a string.  There are well-established ways to do this, just one Stack Overflow search away.

Comment: Recommendation 3: use a fixed buffer size for your digits that accounts for the longest possible `uint64_t` value in whatever base you're trying to convert to.  Count the digits as you convert them.  Usually you won't need to be clever by computing log etc, but if you need to do that, it must also be done with integer functions..  otherwise you will have similar issues (most likely a handful of edge-cases) where precision issues mess you up.  And you might not even know you're getting undefined behavior.  This could lead to catastrophic bugs that are difficult to debug.

Comment: I am not trying to convert to/fro any base, actually, it just did that, as undesirable behaviour.  I am trying to store a crc64 checksum (which gets returned as a uint64_t) into an array.  The checksum will always be like the above example, so the uint64_t res = x72e3daa0aa188782 i want to be stored as an array char digest[8], where digest[0] is 72, digest[1] is e3.. digest[7] is 82..

Comment: Update your question with exactly what you're trying to do then. This partial example at least clarifies what you're trying to do a bit. As said already, `pow` should not be there, and `10` stands out as wrong because you really are taking byte by byte of this uint64_t. And ... full compileable code with output and wanted output would is the standard approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shifting and bit-wise AND can also do what you need. For instance

```
unsigned char digest[8];
int shift = 56;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
{
    digest[i] = (res >> shift) & 0xff;
    shift -= 8;
}
```

If it's okay to change the value of `res` another approach is:

```
for (int i = 7; i >= 0; --i)
{
    digest[i] = res & 0xff;
    res >>= 8;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the second approach further?  Bit shifting was the approach I had anticipated I would get, but couldn't figure it out, but I was doing a more elementary approach but it might have been more appropriate with a six digit integer, but be as it may, I like the shift with bit-wise and.

Comment: @jon The second approach starts by saving the 8 least significant bits of `res`. When it shifts `res` 8 bits to the left. So if you start with `0x72e3daa0aa188782` it will save the `0x82` and then after the shift you have `0x72e3daa0aa1887`. So in the next loop it will save `0x87` and then after the shift you have `0x72e3daa0aa18`. So in the next loop it will save `0x18` and then after the shift you have `0x72e3daa0aa`. And so on.

Answer (score 1):

You should use division by 256, not by 10:

```
unsigned char digest[sizeof(uint64_t) / sizeof(char)];

for (int i = sizeof(digest) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   digest[i] = res % 256; // get the last byte
   res /= 256;            // get the remainder
}

// for demo purposes
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(digest); i++) {
   printf("%x ", digest[i]); 
}

// 72 e3 da a0 aa 18 87 82
```

Comment: Yeah I was thinking base-10 as a starting point, which brought me back to my CS days of doing this (actually it was my very first homework, separating a three digit integer into their individual components).. but i digress, may i ask why the size of division of the array size when the digest will always be 8?  The rest of the divide / modulo is what I was feebly trying to do at least...i guess 2 in the AM coding does that..

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always 1, so `sizeof(uint64_t) / sizeof(char)` => `sizeof(uint64_t)`

Answer (score 1):

Obviously if you divide by 10 you'll get the decimal digits instead of what you expected. In this case you just want to get the underlying bits of `uint64_t` which can be done with a simple `memcpy`. But you're expecting the bytes in big endian order so you'll also need to convert to big endian first

```
uint64_t number = 0x72e3daa0aa188782ull;

#ifdef __unix__
uint64_t number_be = htonll(number);
#else
uint64_t number_be = htobe64(number);
#endif

char digest[8];
memcpy(&digest, &number_be , sizeof number);
```

In C it can also be done with a union

```
union Digest
{
    uint64_t res;
    char bytes[8];
} digest;
digest.res = htonll(0x72e3daa0aa188782ull); // or htobe64
// now just use digest.bytes[]
```

These need only a few machine instructions, hence would be far faster than looping 8 times just to get the 8 bytes

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use a `union` here.

```
union foo {
    uint64_t u64;
    uint8_t u8[8];
};
```

This saves you from having to do any conversion. You can access the 64-bit value using `foo.u64` or the 8-bit values using `foo.u8[0]` to `foo.u8[7]`.

Comment: This won't put the bytes in the right positions because of the endianness issues.

Comment: What endian issues? Worst  likely case is applying `8-i` to the array index, which is trivial.

Comment: I can just reverse it, where u8[0] is the last value and u8[7] is the first..

Comment: Sure, you could do that, but if you do it without understanding _why_ you're doing it, then chances are very high that you're doing it for the wrong reason and you might have the wrong solution.

Comment: I will need to read up more on this method as I haven't worked much with unions, but that being said, why was it reversed from what I expected?

Comment: it'll be reversed only on little endian machines. If the code is compiled for some big endian targets then of course the bytes are already in the expected order

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#define INIT_LIST           \
201234567890123456,       \
12345678901234567890,     \
98765432109876543,        \
65432109887,              \
12345234512345,           \
217631276371261627,       \
12354123512453124,        \
2163521442531,            \
2341232142132321,         \
1233432112

#define STR_(...) #__VA_ARGS__
#define STR(x) STR_(x)

int main (void)
{
  uint64_t numbers[10] = { INIT_LIST };
  char array[] = STR(INIT_LIST);
  puts(array);
}
```